# Keep an element loaded while changing page in pwa

Tags: html, ajax, progressive-web-apps

I'm currently messing with PWA and see how far you can get a simple website when it comes to the feeling of a native app.
Sadly iOS is still very limited. Mainly I'm missing push notification and vibration api.

But now my question:

Is there a possibility to keep an html element (bottom app-like navigation bar) loaded while switching pages?

Right now I've added the Navigation bar including scripts on every page of the website.
When you switch pages, the navigation bar unloads and gets rendered again.
If placed in the head of the document it's a few milliseconds.
Still it's unnecessary and gives away from the "app feeling".

I thought about solutions like:

1. keep the user on a single site with the navigation added, and load pages dynamically through an iframe. But I think this might be a very sketchy solution.
2. Dynamically refresh page content from other pages through ajax calls. Absolutely no Idea if this could be done efficiently and/or makes sense.

Any point in the right direction is welcome.

Comment: I would prefer your second option. This should be achievable.

Comment: I agree, the 2nd option works great in my PWA programs, very fast and efficient.

Comment: Turns out it's called a "SPA" Single page application. Guess this is the way to go. But If I always fetch from server, the pwa cache will be bypassed since it's an ajax request and does not get fetched from pwa cache? Any clarification on how you implemented this? Best regards

Comment: All requests go through the service worker if one is present. It sounds like your fetch handler isn't matching the URL you're sending.